# Spring Post Controller redirection only prints url instead of redirecting

Tags: spring, redirect, post, controller

I have been working on a Spring Boot Application that gets data of a car (licensePlate and brand) and saves it into a database. So far, it is working, but I wanted to redirect to a side after the form submit and instead of redirecting, it only prints out the link it should go to.

This is my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savecar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveCar(@RequestParam("licensePlate") String licensePlate, @RequestParam("brand") String brand, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Car car = new Car(licensePlate, brand);
    carRepository.save(car);
    String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
    return "redirect:" + referer;
}
```

What I get is:

```
redirect:http://localhost:1333/cars
```

in my browser window.
What am I missing? Thanks! If you need an further detail, just ask.

Comment: Remove @ResponseBody from method.

Comment: Well, I was really sure that I tried that before and got an error, but now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am also having this problem but I don't have @ResponseBody in my method... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just as @lzagkaretos said, you need to remove @ResponseBody annotation. The reason why you got a string as a result instead of a redirect with @ResponseBody included is because by combining @ResponseBody with @Controller annotation you actually get @RestController and any returned value will be either in a JSON format (produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) or any other format that you've selected as a return value.